# Creating post out of user profiles Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, search

I was hoping someone could help me, Im needing a way to have user profiles show up when searching. So I want to create a custom post type "Profiles" and have this get automatically created when the admin creates a new user in the dashboard.

So any help would be great or if anyone has any other ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for that. Just create an [Author Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates) to display the information you want for your users.

You should also be able to use this in tandem with [Get Users](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) so that you're not limited to just retrieving users with the the Author role (if necessary).

However, I don't know if users with a role less than "Author" are queried by default in your author.php file. You should probably consider using setting up this template in archive.php if certain roles are giving you problems.

**UPDATE:** If your intention is to store information about a user that's unique to your theme and isn't available through standard Wordpress means, then you will want to look into the [User Register Action Hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register) for automatic generation of Profiles.

By contrast, you'll also want to look into the [Delete User Action Hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/delete_user) to delete your custom profiles automatically.

There are plugins that can help create [Custom Posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) for you, but I would personally build it from the ground up to tailor everything to your needs. You should also look into [Custom Meta Boxes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) to store your unique information.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm, sorry. I'm not sure how creating a authors.php page would help authors profiles show up I'm the loop and search. I'm trying to find a way that users profiles are kinda treated like post n that they show up on my frontpage umongst the posts and when searching. Any ideas thanks?

Comment: Just to be certain, will there be any information in your author profiles that is unique? Meaning their profile information can't be found through standard Wordpress functions?

Comment: All the profiles will be unique. Each profile has different information.. therefore there unique no? Or do you mean custom fields or something? The user profiles will be the standard wordpress profiles maybe with a couple of custom fields. I need these to be displayed via the loop on my homepage. thanks

Comment: I am currently using the "User register Action" hook to dynamically create a new "profile" post which is a custom post when each new user registers. This also includes a custom post template to pull in all the users profile information. Then including this in my loop. sound like the way to go? thanks for all your help mate.

Comment: Sounds like it. Please mark as answered if my update covered everything you needed.